# I want to check checkbox on value basis

Tags: javascript, jquery

AOA,
I need to check checkbox by jquery on values basis. e.g
    
now I want when this page is loaded then this chckbox need to be checked.

Best Regrads,
Musaddiq Khan

Comment: @RichardEv Some kind of greeting, I'm guessing.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: @RichardEv it means Assalam alaikum (may God bless you people)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page-load, you can use the `attribute=value` selector:

```
var valueToFind = 3; // or whatever you're looking for
$('input:checkbox[value="' + valueToFind + '"]').prop('checked',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b9xEM/1/).

References:

- [`[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using the attr command as shown below.

```
$(".abc").attr('checked', true);
```

where abc is the name of the class of the check box like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="abc">
```

If you want to check it when the page loads just use

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".abc").attr('checked', true);
       });
```